# Is it possible to use a TextMate grammar within a DocumentSymbolProvider?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to implement a DocumentSymbolProvider and TreeDataProvider using the tokens and scopes from a textmate grammar. Is there a mechanism that allows for access to these tokens?

I've looked around and found discussions that mentioned it is not possible directly through the vscode api. I'm getting the tokens through regex but looking for a better alternative.